# Chart.js - Where to put global chart configuration?

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to set up a Chart.js line graph with the following code. Where in this do I place the `Chart.defaults.global = {}` or `Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;` code?

Chart.js docs can be found here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

```
<!-- Chart.js -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var data = {
       labels: ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", "Week 6", "Week 7"],
       datasets: [
           {
               label: "My Second dataset",
               fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
               strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
               pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
               pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
               pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
               pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
               data: [86, 74, 68, 49, 42]
           }
       ]
   };

   var options = {
       ...
   };

   var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish what you're looking for. This way

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
var options = Chart.defaults.global = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true  
};
```

or, this way

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true
});
```

However, to make it responsive you'll have to add some extra CSS

```
canvas{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

so there's no need for inline CSS

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/begah/1/edit?html,js,output)

In accordance with the comment of @JustinXL below and the latest version of Chart.js there's no need for extra CSS, so check out the updated version.

[Updated demo](http://jsbin.com/wubiwovaxu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you - that does answer my question and it does make the chart responsive. However, it's so blurred that it's unusable - it looks like it's stretching it from about 100px wide to fill the column.

Comment: @user2608266 Yes, I saw that but at this moment I really don't know why. In the meantime I'll see what it could be done and drop you a note.

Comment: Just to point out, you don't need to change the canvas's width & height in the css. This is like doing re-scaling on the canvas which will result in blurry chart. In your demo, the chart.js link you have referenced is too old. Change it to `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.4/Chart.min.js` and the chart will resize properly.

Comment: @JustinXL  I added an extra info to the answer and aslo updated the jsBin demo. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could set the *options* of your chart, but you can also set the *global* (as you asked) to avoid setting this specific property for each chart you want to instantiate.

You just have to set

```
Chart.defaults.global.elements.responsive = true;
```

before instantiating the chart, in your case, before

```
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
```

*(P.S.: Chartjs V2)*